# Playwright launch server with secured websocket

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, playwright, wss

I finally setup my `Playwright` browser server and I'd like to know how I could connect my clients with secured websocket (wss)?

Node.js Server:

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
    const browserServer = await chromium.launchServer({
        port: 12345,
        chromiumSandbox : false,
    });
    const wsEndpoint = browserServer.wsEndpoint();

    console.log(wsEndpoint);
})();
```

Client (C#)

```
public static async Task Main()
    {
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        var browser = await playwright.Chromium.ConnectAsync("ws://<server>:12345/5f779198c62c45f89119def333831f21"); // Here I would like to connect to wss://<server>:12345/5f779198c62c45f89119def333831f21

        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev/dotnet");
        await page.ScreenshotAsync(new PageScreenshotOptions { Path = "screenshot.png" });
    }
```